# Using jQuery how do you reorder child list elements according to a preset order (listed in a variable)?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a `ul` full of `li` elements. Each `li` elements has a `data-choice` attribute. I also have an array which holds the correct order of those `li` elements (indexed array of those `data-choice` attributes.

Example:

```
["5123ee904210a6ad0d00001c", "5123ee904210a6ad0d00001b", "5123ee904210a6ad0d00001a", "5123ee904210a6ad0d000019"]
```

How do I resort the list based on that array?

I figured this one out, but just thought I would share the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
        var order = ["5123ee904210a6ad0d00001c", "5123ee904210a6ad0d00001b", "5123ee904210a6ad0d00001a", "5123ee904210a6ad0d000019"]
        $elems = this.$('.sorting-question li').remove();

        $elems.sort(function(a, b){
            var a_i = order.indexOf($(a).data('choice'));
            var b_i = order.indexOf($(b).data('choice'));
            return a_i > b_i;
        });

        this.$('.sorting-question').append($elems);
```